# How to smartsearch return synonymous and plural in results?

Tags: smartsearch

I need smartsearch results "was more smart". When I type "sumula" they return "sumulas", too.

"sumulas" is plural of "sumula".

How can I do this?

Comment: What does "they" refer to?

Comment: @Max Did itoctopus solve this for you? Is this resolved?  Can you make your question more clear?

Answer (score 1):

If all your plurals consist of just adding an "s" to the end, then this can easily be done by modifying the smart search plugin to include an "OR" condition that also includes the search word with an "s". If you want very high accuracy, then you will need to add a dictionary to your database, and then query the database for the plural of a word. We actually recently did something very similar, where we included the synonyms of the word in the search (see [here](https://www.itoctopus.com/how-we-modified-the-joomla-search-plugin-to-include-synonyms)). This would take time but it is generally not that complicated.